# Rails 6 modal with webpack bootstrap is not shown in my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I already added jquery by yarn command and repaired some part in **config/webpack/environment.js**.

What and how is connected with **modal.js.erb**?

JQuery is working I tested in **application.html.erb**.

**environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Something strange is that butttons are applied with bootstrap5 but modal not only working.

**app/frontend/js/bootstrap_js_files.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/js/src/alert'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/button'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/carousel'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/collapse'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/dropdown'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/popover'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/tab'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/toast'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/tooltip'
```

**views/articles/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Add user', new_user_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'}  %>
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**views/articles/_modal.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 *Modal content comes here*
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

**views/articles/modal.js.erb**

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'modal') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import '(path) ... bootstrap_js_files.js' in environment.js ?? 
where You import file with bootstraps JS ?
```

My application.js in packs folder looks like this:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
//import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import '../js/bootstrap_js_files.js'  
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all"

Rails.start()
//Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

require('jquery')
...
...
...
```

Comment: app/frontend/js/bootstrap_js_files.js

Comment: import '../js/bootstrap_js_files.js'  if enviroiment.js is in frontend/packs folder

Comment: enviroiment.js is in config/webpack

Comment: You just do not load this .js files. I do not see your folders structure. enviroiment.js has nothing to it. What is your **source_path: app/frontend** and **source_entry_path: packs** in webpacker.yml - app/config/webpacker.yml

Comment: you mean, I have to import bootstrap_js_files in environment.js?